# Xamarin.Forms UWP WebView UI Freezing issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm developing a browser based application using Xamarin.Forms where I've multiple instances of webviews created. When I'm trying to load any online website in webview, while webview rendering the content it freezes the UI. UI frozen for a few seconds based on the content of the website.

I've tried this:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
Webview.Source = "https://www.cnet.com";
});
```

But no luck.

**Updated code:**

I have a grid to hold multiple instances of webview:

```
<Grid x:Name="Parent" BindingContext="{Binding GuideVm, Source={StaticResource VmLocator}}"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
```

I am adding a new webview to the above 'Grid' layout, whenever user opens a new tab:

```
var browser = new WebView { BindingContext = tab };
browser.SetBinding(WebView.SourceProperty, "UrlSource");
browser.SetBinding(WebView.IsVisibleProperty, "IsWebViewVisible");
Parent.Children.Add(browser);
```

I'm loading the content like this:

```
public Command LoadWebCommand => new Command(OnLoadWeb);
public void OnLoadWeb()
{
    try
    {
        IsWebViewVisible = true;
        UrlSource = Url.GetWellFormedUrl();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnLoadWeb exception: " + exception.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

This freeze issue happens like, for example while I am loading www.cnet.com into one tab (which has it's own associated webview) while it loads the content of cnet website, I am trying to open a new tab but it freezes and releases the GUI often times until the webview completely loaded the content of cnet website.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue (UI freeze), however, It takes a few seconds to load webpage complete. Could you share a code sample?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: I've updated my code by editing the post. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I have created a code sample with your code, Unfortunately, I could not reproduce the issue. The previous tab works fine,  when I add new tab.

Comment: Can you pls share your sample project? I'm using visual studio community edition 2017 , Xamarin.Forms latest installed through nuget. Windows 10.10240 build.

Comment: Sure, [this](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/WebViewTest.git) is code sample.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: Thanks for sharing, I looked into your code and realized one thing that you've latest version of Windows build installed (noticed from UWP project file), whereas I've 10.10240 installed in my machine. Because of this missing prerequisite on my machine I couldn't able to test your project. I am updating my machine to latest windows build, will keep you posted here tomorrow. Thanks again for keeping an eye on this and help.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: I've updated my windows and visual studio 2017 to successfully run your project. I tried running it to test and see if it's working without any freeze. Unfortunately the freeze issue appearing from your code too. Here is the screen recorded demo of debugging your code. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tkJh4y-qSu1rz4VTFK8XShdMSf6lnnGS/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I have given you just now, pls let me know if you still can not able to view..

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: Do you have any suggestions on solving this issue?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: Thank you so much, can you suggest me some other options for now to replace webview with? May be some UWP supported render engine which i can make use of for creating a browser like app? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: Why your comments are not being visible? Please make it visible, so that people will understand this issue with the control.